# mypy error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Self" and "A") [operator] in Python dataclasses

Tags: python, types, mypy

I'm working on a project that relies on strict type hinting. The minimal code example that I'm working on will return this mypy error:

```
error.py:15: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Self" and "A")  [operator]
            return self + rhs.to_A()
                          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing_extensions import Self


@dataclass
class A:
    num: int = 0

    def __add__(self, rhs: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)(self.num + rhs.num)

    def add_B(self, rhs: B) -> Self:
        return self + rhs.to_A()

@dataclass
class B:
    num: int

    def to_A(self) -> A:
        return A(self.num)
```

Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `A` you define that you can only add `Self` and `Self`. Your `add_B` method tries to add `Self` and `A`.

Imagine a subclass `A2` of `A`. Now `add_B` will try to pass the `A` object it built with `to_A` into a method that expects an `A2`. That is forbidden, because `A` is not a subclass of `A2`.

That means it is impossible to subclass `A` at all. Mypy probably reports this because it cannot safely know that there are no subclasses or that there will never be subclasses of `A`.

The fix is obvious: accept just `A` for `rhs` in `__add__`.

```py
    ...

    def __add__(self, rhs: 'A') -> Self:
        ...
```